React: Expected “;” but found “:” with Vite and TypeScript
I’m encountering an error while using Vite with TypeScript and ESLint. The error message is as follows:
ERROR: Expected ";" but found ":"
[vite] Pre-transform error: Transform failed with 1 error:
Here are the versions of the tools I’m using:
•   Vite: 5.3.3
•   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin: ^5.62.0
•   @typescript-eslint/parser: ^5.62.0
•   @vitejs/plugin-react: ^4.3.1
•   @storybook/react-vite: ^7.6.20

